# "self" as method attribute

Tags: python, properties, attributes, self

I am attempting to teach myself Python at the moment and I am trying to work my way through a python program, which is essentially a pacman game. Whilst doing so, I discovered the following class call which contains 'self' as a method attribute.

```
game = Game(agents, display, self, catchExceptions=catchExceptions)
```

THE CONTEXT:

This method call is part of the following function:

```
class ClassicGameRules:
    """
    These game rules manage the control flow of a game, deciding when
    and how the game starts and ends.
    """
    def __init__(self, timeout=30):
        self.timeout = timeout

    def newGame( self, layout, pacmanAgent, ghostAgents, display, quiet = False, catchExceptions=False):
    [1] agents = [pacmanAgent] + ghostAgents[:layout.getNumGhosts()] 
    [2] initState = GameState() 
    [3] initState.initialize( layout, len(ghostAgents) ) 
    [4] game = Game(agents, display, self, catchExceptions=catchExceptions) 
    [5] game.state = initState 
    [6] self.initialState = initState.deepCopy()
```

[1] Just to make this a little more palatable, 'agents' contain the pacman and ghost agent objects combined into a list of lists, which when printed looks something like this:

```
[<keyboardAgents.KeyboardAgent instance at 0x1004fe758>, <ghostAgents.RandomGhost instance at 0x1004fe518>, <ghostAgents.RandomGhost instance at 0x1004fe7a0>, <ghostAgents.RandomGhost instance at 0x1004fe950>, <ghostAgents.RandomGhost instance at 0x1004feb90>]
```

[2] initState = GameState(): GameState() is a data object containing all sorts of information about the Game state

[3] initState.initialize( layout, len(ghostAgents) ): initialises the very first game state from a layout array. This layout array lets the program know where the pacman and ghosts spawn, where the food and capsules are displayed and where walls can be found.

[4] game = Game(agents, display, self, catchExceptions=catchExceptions): The Game class manages the control flow, soliciting actions from agents. Agents can be a keyboard agent (controlled by the player, who controls the pacman) and automated agents controlling the ghosts (see [1]).

[5] game.state = initState: copies the content of [2] into the variable game.state.

[6] self.initialState = initState.deepCopy(): deepCopy is a function which runs a copy operation on variables which define the game state of the game board, such as the layout or the position of the food.

CLASS GAME:
Here is the code of the class Game:

```
class Game:
"""
The Game manages the control flow, soliciting actions from agents. 
"""

def __init__( self, agents, display, rules, startingIndex=0, muteAgents=False, catchExceptions=False ):
    self.agentCrashed = False
    self.agents = agents                                           ## agents contain the pacman and ghost agent objects combigned into a list of lists agents = [pacmanAgent] + ghostAgents[:layout.getNumGhosts()]
    self.display = display                                        
    #print("This is the display object" + str(self.display))
    self.rules = rules                                             ## The rules are passed on as the self attribute of the ClassicGameRules class within the call of Game in newGame [REF 115].
    self.startingIndex = startingIndex                             ## starting index is given as default attribute by the __init__ method.
    self.gameOver = False
    self.muteAgents = muteAgents
    self.catchExceptions = catchExceptions
    self.moveHistory = []
    self.totalAgentTimes = [0 for agent in agents]                 ## This creates a list that replaces the list elements of the agents list, which contains the agent objects, with zeros. It looks something like this [0,0,0]
    ##print(self.totalAgentTimes)
    self.totalAgentTimeWarnings = [0 for agent in agents]          
    self.agentTimeout = False
    import cStringIO                                              
    self.agentOutput = [cStringIO.StringIO() for agent in agents]
```

WHAT CONFUSES ME

When game = Game(agents, display, self, catchExceptions=catchExceptions) is called, "self' is passed on to Game as an attribute. In Game the data contained within "self" takes is placed within the "rules" variable.

But does does this variable contain?

Intuitively I would suggest that it would be the "self" instance of the newGame object. But seeing how this method is called self.initialState = initState.deepCopy(), which doesn't seem to make sense...

Or are we referencing the self - object of the ClassicGameRules class?

I know this was a handful of text to read, but I wasn't quite sure how to shorten this question. Please let me know if more information is required. Any help would be highly appreciated. :)

Z_101

Comment: The `__init__` is called with an instance of the current `Game` object as the first parameter (like any other method), which by convention is called `self`. Your `__init__` method is just like any other method, it's just called automatically after the object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
game = Game(agents, display, self, catchExceptions=catchExceptions)
```

in `ClassicGameRules.newGame` calls `Game.__init__` with three positional arguments and one keyword argument, plus the implicit first positional argument of the new `Game` instance. `Game.__init__` is defined as:

```
def __init__(self, agents, display, rules, startingIndex=0, muteAgents=False, catchExceptions=False ): 
                 # agents  display  self   [default]        [default]         catchExceptions
```

Crucially, the `self` in the calling function is *not* the same as the `self` in the called function. This call passes the `ClassicGameRules` instance as the argument `rules` to the `Game` instance. This creates a two-way link:

- You can access the `Game` instance within `ClassicGameRules` instance methods via `self.game`; and
- You can access the `ClassicGameRules` instance within `Game` instance methods via `self.rules`.

The next part:

```
game.state = initState 
self.initialState = initState.deepCopy()
```

sets the `state` attribute of the `Game` instance to `initState`, but then saves a *copy* of that state to `self.initialState` (where `self` refers to the `ClassicGameRules` instance, as we're inside a `ClassicGameRules` instance method).

Comment: Thank you jornsharpe. I get it now :)!

Answer (score 1):

In the method `newGame` of the class `ClassicGameRules`, `self` represents the current instance of the class:

```
game = Game(       agents, display, self, ...) 
                      v       v       v
def __init__(self, agents, display, rules, ...)
```

The first `self` of the `__init__` method here is to represents to the new object that will be created in the `Game` class.

In your case, the `Game` class has in `rules` a reference to the instance of `ClassicGameRules` which called the constructor of the `Game` instance. The `deepCopy` after has nothing to do and is just to synchronized the initial state of both objects, by coping the state of the object just created (`game`) into the "parent" object (instance of `ClassicGameRules`).

Comment: Thank you Maxime Lorant. This was very  helpful!